# BigQuery: How to represent integer of type Long in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis, integer-arithmetic

I have a dataset that contains integer of type “**Long**”. I need to analyse that dataset by doing some arithmetic operations on it.  What are the possible ways to do that?

I have tried casting to FLOAT but then I can't use some operations like bitwise AND etc on that data type.

As an example, here is the value of one field

```
18446744073709551615
```

Thanks

Comment: just for reference - for what kind of work would you require doing bitwise operations over longs?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numeric` if you want to keep a number and all its decimal points:

```
select cast('18446744073709551615' as numeric)
```

This is not infinitely flexible.  It is actually equivalent to `numeric(38, 9)` in any other database.  BigQuery offers no control over the scale and precision.  This is described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-types) (admittedly, this is a very recent addition to BigQuery).

Comment: Unable to use bitwise operations on it. 

Error: Bitwise operator & requires two integer/BYTES arguments of the same type, but saw NUMERIC and NUMERIC

Comment: @john . . . Ouch.  Bitwise operations will require a bit of trickery.  But you can always use `* 2` and `/ 2`.

Comment: I had tried to break the logic by breaking big long integer into two small integers and then performing operations on it. Basic operations like +, -, *, / worked fine but things got complicated with bitwise & operation. 

I would really appreciate if you have any better idea. :)

Comment: Can you file a feature request on [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B)?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Done :)

Answer (score 3):

The long range for integer is :

> The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed
>   long has a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1

In BigQuery normal Integer long is represented by INT64(INTEGER).

Google Big-Query documentation : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#integer_type.

**
Basically, long maps to `INTEGER` (INT64) which has a larger range in bigquery.
**

So, if you keep it as INTEGER type, and the arithmethic operation doesn't result in decimal points to the final value, you should be okay in representing with data type INTEGER in BigQuery.